# how to send a file to run in php scripts?

Tags: php

I am trying to drag and drop photos in my website and then I need to upload them to the server. I have done dnd in html5 but I need to know as to how I can upload the file on the server.

```
var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
var reader = new FileReader();
```

I have the dnd listeners which call my filehandler function where I get the file as above. I have another file upload.php where I have written the script for uploading files on my server.

How do I link the file to the PHP script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many tutorials available for this

- http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/drag-and-drop-upload
- http://www.appelsiini.net/2009/10/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-file-upload
- http://verens.com/2009/12/28/multiple-file-uploads-using-html5/